# Display True and False Choices in Quiz App

Tags: swift, swiftui

[image]

This is an Flag Quiz app, there are 4 choices according to flag image of any country. What I want to achieve is both of these logics:

- **Logic 1**: If user selected true choice, only mark true choice as green
- **Logic 2**: If user selected false choice, selected choice will be red, but true choice will be shown as green (others standard as gray)

I could achieve first logic, but I wasn't able to for second one, too.

**Choice Button Custom View**

```swift
struct ChoiceButton : View {
    
    var countryName: String
    
    var body: some View {
        
        Text("\(countryName)")
            .font(Font.custom(FontManager.Montserrat.semiBold, size: 16))
            .foregroundStyle(Color.textSoftBlack)
            .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
            .lineLimit(2)
            .padding(.horizontal)
            .padding(.leading,32)
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: 140, alignment: .leading)
            .background(
                
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 16)
                    .foregroundStyle(Color.buttonGray) //maybe some logic here?)
            )
    }
}
```

**Quiz View**

```swift
ForEach(quizManager.choiceList, id:\.self){ item in
    Button {
        quizManager.selectAnswer(answer: item)
    } label: {
        ChoiceButton(countryName: "\(item.name)")
            .frame(maxHeight: 80)
    }
}
```

**Quiz Manager (Observable Object)**

```swift
@Published var currentTrueAnswer //holds true answer in every quizView load
@Published var answerSelected = false //when user made choice, it sets to true so I cando button UI logics.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could consider using an enum to represent the display state of a button. The enum could also be associated with a `Color`. Something like:

```swift
enum DisplayState {
    case notSelected
    case correctAnswer
    case wrongAnswer

    var color: Color {
        switch self {
        case .notSelected: .gray
        case .correctAnswer: .green
        case .wrongAnswer: .red
        }
    }
}
```

In your `ForEach`, you could then pass the state to each button as a read-only value. The name can also be read-only too:

```swift
Button {
    quizManager.selectAnswer(answer: item)
} label: {
    ChoiceButton(
        countryName: "\(item.name)",
        displayState: stateForAnswer(answer: item)
    )
    .frame(maxHeight: 80)
}
```

```swift
struct ChoiceButton : View {

    let countryName: String
    let displayState: DisplayState

    var body: some View {
        Text("\(countryName)")
            // other modifiers as before
            .background(
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 16)
                    .foregroundStyle(displayState.color)
            )
    }
}
```

That just leaves the evaluation of the state. It would work well to use an optional for the selection, that way the boolean flag `answerSelected` is not needed. The function `stateForAnswer` could then be implemented something like this:

```swift
@State private var selectedAnswer: Answer?

private func stateForAnswer(answer: Answer) -> DisplayState {
    if let selectedAnswer {
        if answer == currentTrueAnswer {
            .correctAnswer
        } else if answer == selectedAnswer {
            .wrongAnswer
        } else {
            .notSelected
        }
    } else {
        .notSelected
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it works well! And helped me to understand more.

Answer (score 1):

Code for quiz for:

- infinity amount of quiz answers
- any sort of displayed data
- minimal "manual" code support

all you need is to set

1. answers;
2. correct answer
   inside of QuizModel.

[image]

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct TestSwiftUIApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var model = QuizModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ForEach(model.quizAnswers, id: \.self) { itemModel in
                Text(itemModel.item)
                    .overlay(Color.clickableAlpha) // will got click on empty spaces also
                    .background(itemModel.color)
                    .onTapGesture { 
                         model.colorAnswers(clickedItem: itemModel.item) 
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}

public class QuizModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var quizAnswers = ["Answ 1", "Answ 2", "Answ 3", "Answ 4", "Answ 5", "Answ 6"].map{ QuizAnswer($0) }
    let correctAnswer = "Answ 1";
    @Published var lockAnswers = false
    
    func colorAnswers(clickedItem: String) {
        guard lockAnswers == false else { return }
        
        guard let idx = quizAnswers.firstIndex(where: { $0.item == clickedItem }) else { return }
        
        if quizAnswers[idx].item == correctAnswer {
            quizAnswers[idx].color = .green
            lockAnswers = true
            return
        }
        
        guard let idx2 = quizAnswers.firstIndex(where: { $0.item == correctAnswer }) else { return }
        quizAnswers[idx].color = .red
        quizAnswers[idx2].color = .green
        lockAnswers = true
    }
}

public struct QuizAnswer<T>: Hashable where T: Hashable {
    public static func == (lhs: QuizAnswer<T>, rhs: QuizAnswer<T>) -> Bool {
        lhs.hashValue == rhs.hashValue
    }
    
    public func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        hasher.combine(item)
    }
    
    public let item: T
    public var color : Color = .clear
    
    public init(_ item: T) {
        self.item = item
    }
}

public extension Color {
    init(rgbaHex: UInt32) {
        self.init(
            red:      Double((rgbaHex >> 24) & 0xFF) / 256.0,
            green:    Double((rgbaHex >> 16) & 0xFF) / 256.0,
            blue:     Double((rgbaHex >> 8) & 0xFF) / 256.0,
            opacity:  Double(rgbaHex & 0xFF) / 256.0
        )
    }
    
    static var clickableAlpha: Color { get { return Color(rgbaHex: 0x01010101) } }
}
```