# SwiftUI state update

Tags: swift, swiftui

I thought I had a very good understanding of how SwiftUI works. But sometimes something still confuses me especially when state is involved. Here are some basic codes.

Firstly, I have a model.

```
struct Item : Equatable {
    let id = UUID()
    let name: String
}
```

And a ViewModel

```
@Observable
final class ContentViewModel {
    
    var items = [
        Item(name: "test1"),
        Item(name: "test2"),
        Item(name: "test3")
    ]
    
    func mark(item: Item, wrong: Bool) {
        //deal with right or wrong answer
        items.removeAll {
            $0 == item
        }
    }
    
}
```

And some views

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    let viewModel = ContentViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        if let item = viewModel.items.first {
            BackwardableView(item) {
                QuizView(item, fallback: $0)
            }
                .environment(viewModel)
        }
    }
}

struct QuizView : View {
    
    private let item: Item
    @Binding private var fallback: Bool
    @Environment(ContentViewModel.self) private var viewModel
    
    init(_ item: Item, fallback: Binding<Bool>) {
        self.item = item
        self._fallback = fallback
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Quiz \(item.name)")
            Button("Wrong Answer") {
                fallback = true
            }
            Button("Correct Answer") {
                viewModel.mark(item: item, wrong: false)
            }
        }
        
    }
}

struct FallbackView : View {
    
    private let item: Item
    @Environment(ContentViewModel.self) private var viewModel
    
    init(_ item: Item) {
        self.item = item
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("Fallback \(item.name)")
            .toolbar {
                Button("Next") {
                    viewModel.mark(item: item, wrong: true)
                }
            }
    }
}

struct BackwardableView<Content: View> : View {
    
    private let item: Item
    private let content: (Binding<Bool>) -> Content
    
    @Environment(ContentViewModel.self) private var viewModel
    @State private var backward = false
    
    init(_ item: Item, content: @escaping (Binding<Bool>) -> Content) {
        self.item = item
        self.content = content
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        Group {
            if backward {
                FallbackView(item)
            } else {
                content($backward)
            }
        }
              .id(item.id)
//            .onChange(of: item) { oldValue, newValue in
//                if oldValue == newValue {
//                    return
//                }
//                backward = false
//            }
    }
}
```

The problem occurs in the last view. Whenever a fallback is triggered by QuizView, it should switch to the fallback view and perform some fallback actions. In this mock code, it simply asks the viewModel to remove the first item and jump to the next one. However, the BackwardableView seems to retain the "backward state" for the next item, which is illogical.

I tried adding an explicit id to differentiate this view as completely new. This trick often works, as I assume it allows SwiftUI to recognize it as a distinct view. However, it's not effective in this case. Adding the onChange modifier resolves the issue. While I understand this approach works, I'm still confused about how the view, which is supposedly a struct with immutable properties (including the item), can apparently change.

Comment: check the docs for how to use `@State` with `Observable`, e.g. it could be optional and init in onAppear https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/state

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never set `backward` to false, except its initial value.

If you want to use the `.id(item.id)` approach, you should understand that this works by giving a view a new ID, hence resetting all its `@State`. In this case, you want the `backward` state to be reset, so you should put `.id` on `BackwardableView` (which contains `backward`), not the `Group` that wraps the if statement.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var viewModel = ContentViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        if let item = viewModel.items.first {
            BackwardableView(item) {
                QuizView(item, fallback: $0)
            }
            .environment(viewModel)
            .id(item.id) // put it here!
        }
    }
}
```

In my opinion though, adding an extra `Binding` to `FallbackView` is better, because this doesn't involve recreating the entire view.

```
struct FallbackView : View {
    
    private let item: Item
    @Environment(ContentViewModel.self) private var viewModel
    
    @Binding var backward: Bool
    
    init(_ item: Item, _ backward: Binding<Bool>) {
        self.item = item
        self._backward = backward
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("Fallback \(item.name)")
            .toolbar {
                Button("Next") {
                    viewModel.mark(item: item, wrong: true)
                    backward = false // reset backward here!
                }
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: you can't init objects with `@State` like that its a memory leak

Comment: @malhal You can if the object is `@Observable`.

Comment: It's a leak, @State should be optional and init it in onAppear, see the docs https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/state

Comment: @malhal Oh I see, they have updated the docs. Sure, allocating an object every time `init` is called can be expensive, but the object will be de-initialised almost immediately, so it's not a "leak". In any case, this isn't the focus of the question.

Comment: Yes that but also others have reported the initial object never deinits

Comment: @malhal Of course the initial object is not de-initialised. Why is this unexpected? It would only de-initialise when the view is destroyed. Using macOS 14.1.1, I can see that this is exactly what happens using the memory graph debugger.

Comment: they must have fixed that then

Answer (score 0):

1. for better understanding SwiftUI, please read the following comment. It is a little bit old, but it will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62919526/4423545
2. If you need to build quiz app, this link will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78129072/4423545

---

about your question:

3. I prefer to do not use "@Observable" because of it gives you less control than older "StateObject/ObservableObject". It forces much more useless refreshes of UI. I believe that swiftUI is not that lightweight to use "@Observable".

```
struct Item : Equatable {
    let id = UUID()
    let name: String
}

// used ObservableObject instead of @Observed
class ContentViewModel: ObservableObject { 
    // OPTIMIZED
    var items = ["test1", "test2", "test3"].map{ Item(name: $0) }

    func mark(item: Item, wrong: Bool) {
        items.removeAll {
            $0 == item
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    //HERE is missed @StateObject / @ObservedObject [or @State for newer system with @Observed model]
    @StateObject var model = ContentViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        if let item = viewModel.items.first {
            BackwardableView(item) {
                QuizView(item, fallback: $0)
            }
            .environment(model)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `ObservedObject` is used when when passing around an `ObservableObject` that has its lifecycle managed somewhere else. `StateObject` is for initializing in a `View`

Comment: @loremipsum yep, exactly. And here model is ObservableObject as you see in code. And just above code you see that I prefer to use `ObservableObject` and why so.

Comment: @loremipsum and by the way... `StateObject` and `ObservedObject` is THE SAME THING. From documentation: ```StateObject - A property wrapper type that instantiates an observable object.``` ; https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/stateobject ; So there is no matter what do you prefer to use - `@StateObject` or `@ObservedObject` -- IT IS THE SAME THING.

Comment: When you use `@ObservedObject` and the assignment, the right hand expression will be executed every time you create the struct. This is _not_ what we want. On the other hand, if you have `@StateObject` and the assignment, the right hand expression is actually an "autoclosure" which gets executed only once - when the underlying view object will be created. This is what we want in this case.

Comment: @CouchDeveloper do you think it is so or YOU HAVE CHECKED?))) No it is not. Just create temporary project ad check by your hands. `@ObservedObject` and `@StateObject` is synonyms. They works absolutely the same and its assign only once -- on first struct(view) creation. On recreation values will NOT be reassigned.

Comment: I have a few large projects builded and published on AppStore with usage ```@ObservedObject``` with each ViewModel and there are no such behaviour as you talk about :)

Comment: Have you actually looked at the documentation for ObservedObject? https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/observedobject They are not equal StateObject can manage lifecycle and ObservedObject cannot. The documentation tells you exactly how to use it, don't take my word for it.

Comment: Notice in the ObservedObject documentation Apple says “Don’t specify a default or initial value for the observed object. Use the attribute only for a property that acts as an input for a view, as in the above example.” It specifically states not to do what you are doing.

Comment: @loremipsum argument.